# Web scraping table elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

I'm currently trying to web scrape the 2018 fantasy football player rankings from espn website and import that information into a csv file. Currently my program is able to successfully scrape but it only grabs the first element for each class tag I search through. I used the `soup.find_all('')` method but that still doesn't seem to get the entire table. Here is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# pass in the url to be parsed
ff_rank_url = 'http://www.espn.com/fantasy/football/story/_/page/18RanksPreseason300PPR/2018-fantasy-football-ppr-rankings-top-300'

source = requests.get(ff_rank_url).text

# create parsed soup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

# grab top 300 ppr rankings for 2018
ff_table = soup.find('aside')

# print(ff_table.prettify())
# grabbing players in that table

# players = ff_table.find('table', class_='inline-table').text
# print(players)

for player in soup.find_all('table', class_='inline-table'):
    players = player.tbody.tr.text
    print(players)
```

basically how would I be able to get this exact table into python?

Comment: try using pandas to read html content, they are better at parsing tables

Comment: I guess my question from here is when should I use beautiful soup to scrap?

Comment: beautifulsoup works better on text etc, its more fundamental and dynamic, pandas as best for tables etc

Comment: awesome, greatly appreciate the feedback

Comment: happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you nice tables from the website:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# pass in the url to be parsed
ff_rank_url = 'http://www.espn.com/fantasy/football/story/_/page/18RanksPreseason300PPR/2018-fantasy-football-ppr-rankings-top-300'

source = requests.get(ff_rank_url).text

table_1=pd.read_html(source)[0]
table_2=pd.read_html(source)[1]
```

The second table has clubbed rank and player together you can remove that as the index will be the rank. This line of code will take care of it.

```
table_2['Rank, Player'] = table_2['Rank, Player'].str.replace('\d+\.', '')
table_2.rename(columns={"Rank, Player": "Player"},inplace=True)
```

[image: you will get a nice table that looks like this]

Comment: Awesome, this is much better and way more simpler. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, do accept my answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the outer table and then scrape the names:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from collections import namedtuple
player = namedtuple('player', ['rank', 'name', 'position', 'team', 'posrank'])
d = soup(requests.get('http://www.espn.com/fantasy/football/story/_/page/18RanksPreseason300PPR/2018-fantasy-football-ppr-rankings-top-300').text, 'html.parser')
_, *data = [[i.text for i in c.find_all('td')] for c in d.find_all('aside', {'class':'inline inline-table'})[1].find('table').find_all('tr')]
parsed_result = [[*re.split('(?<=\d)\.\s', a), *d] for a, *d in data]
final_output = [player(*i) for i in parsed_result]
```

Output:

```
[player(rank='1', name="Le'Veon Bell", position='RB', team='PIT', posrank='RB1'), player(rank='2', name='Todd Gurley II', position='RB', team='LAR', posrank='RB2'), player(rank='3', name='David Johnson', position='RB', team='ARI', posrank='RB3'), player(rank='4', name='Antonio Brown', position='WR', team='PIT', posrank='WR1'), player(rank='5', name='Ezekiel Elliott', position='RB', team='DAL', posrank='RB4'), player(rank='6', name='Saquon Barkley', position='RB', team='NYG', posrank='RB5'), player(rank='7', name='Alvin Kamara', position='RB', team='NO', posrank='RB6'), player(rank='8', name='Julio Jones', position='WR', team='ATL', posrank='WR2'), player(rank='9', name='DeAndre Hopkins', position='WR', team='HOU', posrank='WR3'), player(rank='10', name='Odell Beckham Jr.', position='WR', team='NYG', posrank='WR4'), player(rank='11', name='Kareem Hunt', position='RB', team='KC', posrank='RB7'), player(rank='12', name='Keenan Allen', position='WR', team='LAC', posrank='WR5'), player(rank='13', name='Dalvin Cook', position='RB', team='MIN', posrank='RB8'), player(rank='14', name='Leonard Fournette', position='RB', team='JAC', posrank='RB9'), player(rank='15', name='Melvin Gordon', position='RB', team='LAC', posrank='RB10'), player(rank='16', name='Michael Thomas', position='WR', team='NO', posrank='WR6'), player(rank='17', name='A.J. Green', position='WR', team='CIN', posrank='WR7'), player(rank='18', name='LeSean McCoy', position='RB', team='BUF', posrank='RB11'), player(rank='19', name='Christian McCaffrey', position='RB', team='CAR', posrank='RB12'), player(rank='20', name='Devonta Freeman', position='RB', team='ATL', posrank='RB13'), player(rank='21', name='Davante Adams', position='WR', team='GB', posrank='WR8'), player(rank='22', name='Rob Gronkowski', position='TE', team='NE', posrank='TE1'), player(rank='23', name='Mike Evans', position='WR', team='TB', posrank='WR9'), player(rank='24', name='Adam Thielen', position='WR', team='MIN', posrank='WR10'), player(rank='25', name='Larry Fitzgerald', position='WR', team='ARI', posrank='WR11'), player(rank='26', name='T.Y. Hilton', position='WR', team='IND', posrank='WR12'), player(rank='27', name='Doug Baldwin', position='WR', team='SEA', posrank='WR13'), player(rank='28', name='Stefon Diggs', position='WR', team='MIN', posrank='WR14'), player(rank='29', name='Travis Kelce', position='TE', team='KC', posrank='TE2'), player(rank='30', name='Zach Ertz', position='TE', team='PHI', posrank='TE3'), player(rank='31', name='Tyreek Hill', position='WR', team='KC', posrank='WR15'), player(rank='32', name='Demaryius Thomas', position='WR', team='DEN', posrank='WR16'), player(rank='33', name='Allen Robinson', position='WR', team='CHI', posrank='WR17'), player(rank='34', name='Golden Tate', position='WR', team='DET', posrank='WR18'), player(rank='35', name='Josh Gordon', position='WR', team='CLE', posrank='WR19'), player(rank='36', name='Jerick McKinnon', position='RB', team='SF', posrank='RB14'), player(rank='37', name='Joe Mixon', position='RB', team='CIN', posrank='RB15'), player(rank='38', name='Jordan Howard', position='RB', team='CHI', posrank='RB16'), player(rank='39', name='Alshon Jeffery', position='WR', team='PHI', posrank='WR20'), player(rank='40', name='Amari Cooper', position='WR', team='OAK', posrank='WR21'), player(rank='41', name='JuJu Smith-Schuster', position='WR', team='PIT', posrank='WR22'), player(rank='42', name='Jarvis Landry', position='WR', team='CLE', posrank='WR23'), player(rank='43', name='Kenyan Drake', position='RB', team='MIA', posrank='RB17'), player(rank='44', name='Derrius Guice', position='RB', team='WAS', posrank='RB18'), player(rank='45', name='Royce Freeman', position='RB', team='DEN', posrank='RB19'), player(rank='46', name='Rashaad Penny', position='RB', team='SEA', posrank='RB20'), player(rank='47', name='Sony Michel', position='RB', team='NE', posrank='RB21'), player(rank='48', name='Ronald Jones II', position='RB', team='TB', posrank='RB22'), player(rank='49', name='Alex Collins', position='RB', team='BAL', posrank='RB23'), player(rank='50', name='Marshawn Lynch', position='RB', team='OAK', posrank='RB24'), player(rank='51', name='Marvin Jones Jr.', position='WR', team='DET', posrank='WR24'), player(rank='52', name='Robert Woods', position='WR', team='LAR', posrank='WR25'), player(rank='53', name='Emmanuel Sanders', position='WR', team='DEN', posrank='WR26'), player(rank='54', name='Michael Crabtree', position='WR', team='BAL', posrank='WR27'), player(rank='55', name='Jay Ajayi', position='RB', team='PHI', posrank='RB25'), player(rank='56', name='Derrick Henry', position='RB', team='TEN', posrank='RB26'), player(rank='57', name='Dion Lewis', position='RB', team='TEN', posrank='RB27'), player(rank='58', name='Mark Ingram', position='RB', team='NO', posrank='RB28'), player(rank='59', name='Duke Johnson Jr.', position='RB', team='CLE', posrank='RB29'), player(rank='60', name='Pierre Garcon', position='WR', team='SF', posrank='WR28'), player(rank='61', name='Chris Hogan', position='WR', team='NE', posrank='WR29'), player(rank='62', name='Brandin Cooks', position='WR', team='LAR', posrank='WR30'), player(rank='63', name='Corey Davis', position='WR', team='TEN', posrank='WR31'), player(rank='64', name='Aaron Rodgers', position='QB', team='GB', posrank='QB1'), player(rank='65', name='Tom Brady', position='QB', team='NE', posrank='QB2'), player(rank='66', name='Sammy Watkins', position='WR', team='KC', posrank='WR32'), player(rank='67', name='Randall Cobb', position='WR', team='GB', posrank='WR33'), player(rank='68', name='Devin Funchess', position='WR', team='CAR', posrank='WR34'), player(rank='69', name='Will Fuller V', position='WR', team='HOU', posrank='WR35'), player(rank='70', name='Cooper Kupp', position='WR', team='LAR', posrank='WR36'), player(rank='71', name='DeVante Parker', position='WR', team='MIA', posrank='WR37'), player(rank='72', name='Robby Anderson', position='WR', team='NYJ', posrank='WR38'), player(rank='73', name='Greg Olsen', position='TE', team='CAR', posrank='TE4'), player(rank='74', name='Delanie Walker', position='TE', team='TEN', posrank='TE5'), player(rank='75', name='Evan Engram', position='TE', team='NYG', posrank='TE6'), player(rank='76', name='Lamar Miller', position='RB', team='HOU', posrank='RB30'), player(rank='77', name='Julian Edelman', position='WR', team='NE', posrank='WR39'), player(rank='78', name='Kelvin Benjamin', position='WR', team='BUF', posrank='WR40'), player(rank='79', name='Kerryon Johnson', position='RB', team='DET', posrank='RB31'), player(rank='80', name='Cam Newton', position='QB', team='CAR', posrank='QB3'), player(rank='81', name='Carson Wentz', position='QB', team='PHI', posrank='QB4'), player(rank='82', name='Russell Wilson', position='QB', team='SEA', posrank='QB5'), player(rank='83', name='Deshaun Watson', position='QB', team='HOU', posrank='QB6'), player(rank='84', name='Jordan Reed', position='TE', team='WAS', posrank='TE7'), player(rank='85', name='Tevin Coleman', position='RB', team='ATL', posrank='RB32'), player(rank='86', name='Tarik Cohen', position='RB', team='CHI', posrank='RB33'), player(rank='87', name='Chris Thompson', position='RB', team='WAS', posrank='RB34'), player(rank='88', name='Jamison Crowder', position='WR', team='WAS', posrank='WR41'), player(rank='89', name='DeSean Jackson', position='WR', team='TB', posrank='WR42'), player(rank='90', name='Jimmy Graham', position='TE', team='GB', posrank='TE8'), player(rank='91', name='Jordy Nelson', position='WR', team='OAK', posrank='WR43'), player(rank='92', name='Marquise Goodwin', position='WR', team='SF', posrank='WR44'), player(rank='93', name='Dez Bryant', position='WR', team='FA', posrank='WR45'), player(rank='94', name='Marlon Mack', position='RB', team='IND', posrank='RB35'), player(rank='95', name='Jamaal Williams', position='RB', team='GB', posrank='RB36'), player(rank='96', name='Isaiah Crowell', position='RB', team='NYJ', posrank='RB37'), player(rank='97', name='Rex Burkhead', position='RB', team='NE', posrank='RB38'), player(rank='98', name="D'Onta Foreman", position='RB', team='HOU', posrank='RB39'), player(rank='99', name='Kyle Rudolph', position='TE', team='MIN', posrank='TE9'), player(rank='100', name='Ty Montgomery', position='RB', team='GB', posrank='RB40'), player(rank='101', name='Marqise Lee', position='WR', team='JAC', posrank='WR46'), player(rank='102', name='Josh Doctson', position='WR', team='WAS', posrank='WR47'), player(rank='103', name='Kenny Stills', position='WR', team='MIA', posrank='WR48'), player(rank='104', name='Sterling Shepard', position='WR', team='NYG', posrank='WR49'), player(rank='105', name='Nelson Agholor', position='WR', team='PHI', posrank='WR50'), player(rank='106', name='Rishard Matthews', position='WR', team='TEN', posrank='WR51'), player(rank='107', name='Nick Chubb', position='RB', team='CLE', posrank='RB41'), player(rank='108', name='Carlos Hyde', position='RB', team='CLE', posrank='RB42'), player(rank='109', name='Giovani Bernard', position='RB', team='CIN', posrank='RB43'), player(rank='110', name='Jack Doyle', position='TE', team='IND', posrank='TE10'), player(rank='111', name='Trey Burton', position='TE', team='CHI', posrank='TE11'), player(rank='112', name='Devontae Booker', position='RB', team='DEN', posrank='RB44'), player(rank='113', name='Theo Riddick', position='RB', team='DET', posrank='RB45'), player(rank='114', name='James White', position='RB', team='NE', posrank='RB46'), player(rank='115', name='Allen Hurns', position='WR', team='DAL', posrank='WR52'), player(rank='116', name='Paul Richardson', position='WR', team='WAS', posrank='WR53'), player(rank='117', name='Ben Roethlisberger', position='QB', team='PIT', posrank='QB7'), player(rank='118', name='Kirk Cousins', position='QB', team='MIN', posrank='QB8'), player(rank='119', name='Andrew Luck', position='QB', team='IND', posrank='QB9'), player(rank='120', name='Tyler Eifert', position='TE', team='CIN', posrank='TE12'), player(rank='121', name='Kenny Golladay', position='WR', team='DET', posrank='WR54'), player(rank='122', name='Mohamed Sanu', position='WR', team='ATL', posrank='WR55'), player(rank='123', name='D.J. Moore', position='WR', team='CAR', posrank='WR56'), player(rank='124', name='Tyler Lockett', position='WR', team='SEA', posrank='WR57'), player(rank='125', name='Calvin Ridley', position='WR', team='ATL', posrank='WR58'), player(rank='126', name='Michael Gallup', position='WR', team='DAL', posrank='WR59'), player(rank='127', name='Matthew Stafford', position='QB', team='DET', posrank='QB10'), player(rank='128', name='Drew Brees', position='QB', team='NO', posrank='QB11'), player(rank='129', name='Cameron Meredith', position='WR', team='NO', posrank='WR60'), player(rank='130', name='Jordan Matthews', position='WR', team='NE', posrank='WR61'), player(rank='131', name='John Ross', position='WR', team='CIN', posrank='WR62'), player(rank='132', name='Martavis Bryant', position='WR', team='OAK', posrank='WR63'), player(rank='133', name='Anthony Miller', position='WR', team='CHI', posrank='WR64'), player(rank='134', name='Christian Kirk', position='WR', team='ARI', posrank='WR65'), player(rank='135', name='Albert Wilson', position='WR', team='MIA', posrank='WR66'), player(rank='136', name='Zay Jones', position='WR', team='BUF', posrank='WR67'), player(rank='137', name='James Washington', position='WR', team='PIT', posrank='WR68'), player(rank='138', name='Mike Williams', position='WR', team='LAC', posrank='WR69'), player(rank='139', name='Aaron Jones', position='RB', team='GB', posrank='RB47'), player(rank='140', name='Kenneth Dixon', position='RB', team='BAL', posrank='RB48'), player(rank='141', name='Charles Clay', position='TE', team='BUF', posrank='TE13'), player(rank='142', name='Philip Rivers', position='QB', team='LAC', posrank='QB12'), player(rank='143', name='Patrick Mahomes', position='QB', team='KC', posrank='QB13'), player(rank='144', name='Jordan Wilkins', position='RB', team='IND', posrank='RB49'), player(rank='145', name='C.J. Anderson', position='RB', team='CAR', posrank='RB50'), player(rank='146', name='Elijah McGuire', position='RB', team='NYJ', posrank='RB51'), player(rank='147', name='David Njoku', position='TE', team='CLE', posrank='TE14'), player(rank='148', name='Jimmy Garoppolo', position='QB', team='SF', posrank='QB14'), player(rank='149', name='Alex Smith', position='QB', team='WAS', posrank='QB15'), player(rank='150', name='Latavius Murray', position='RB', team='MIN', posrank='RB52'), player(rank='151', name='Chris Carson', position='RB', team='SEA', posrank='RB53'), player(rank='152', name='Nyheim Hines', position='RB', team='IND', posrank='RB54'), player(rank='153', name='Matt Breida', position='RB', team='SF', posrank='RB55'), player(rank='154', name='Jaguars D/ST', position='DST', team='JAC', posrank='DST1'), player(rank='155', name='Cameron Brate', position='TE', team='TB', posrank='TE15'), player(rank='156', name='Donte Moncrief', position='WR', team='JAC', posrank='WR70'), player(rank='157', name='Mike Wallace', position='WR', team='PHI', posrank='WR71'), player(rank='158', name='Terrelle Pryor Sr.', position='WR', team='NYJ', posrank='WR72'), player(rank='159', name='Doug Martin', position='RB', team='OAK', posrank='RB56'), player(rank='160', name='Matt Ryan', position='QB', team='ATL', posrank='QB16'), player(rank='161', name='Marcus Mariota', position='QB', team='TEN', posrank='QB17'), player(rank='162', name='Dak Prescott', position='QB', team='DAL', posrank='QB18'), player(rank='163', name='Jared Goff', position='QB', team='LAR', posrank='QB19'), player(rank='164', name='George Kittle', position='TE', team='SF', posrank='TE16'), player(rank='165', name='Chris Godwin', position='WR', team='TB', posrank='WR73'), player(rank='166', name='Austin Seferian-Jenkins', position='TE', team='JAC', posrank='TE17'), player(rank='167', name='LeGarrette Blount', position='RB', team='DET', posrank='RB57'), player(rank='168', name='Mitchell Trubisky', position='QB', team='CHI', posrank='QB20'), player(rank='169', name='Ted Ginn Jr.', position='WR', team='NO', posrank='WR74'), player(rank='170', name='Eagles D/ST', position='DST', team='PHI', posrank='DST2'), player(rank='171', name='Rams D/ST', position='DST', team='LAR', posrank='DST3'), player(rank='172', name='Vikings D/ST', position='DST', team='MIN', posrank='DST4'), player(rank='173', name='Texans D/ST', position='DST', team='BAL', posrank='DST5'), player(rank='174', name='Ravens D/ST', position='DST', team='HOU', posrank='DST6'), player(rank='175', name='Greg Zuerlein', position='K', team='LAR', posrank='K1'), player(rank='176', name='Stephen Gostkowski', position='K', team='NE', posrank='K2'), player(rank='177', name='Justin Tucker', position='K', team='BAL', posrank='K3'), player(rank='178', name='Patriots D/ST', position='DST', team='NE', posrank='DST7'), player(rank='179', name='Chargers D/ST', position='DST', team='LAC', posrank='DST8'), player(rank='180', name='Broncos D/ST', position='DST', team='DEN', posrank='DST9'), player(rank='181', name='Panthers D/ST', position='DST', team='CAR', posrank='DST10'), player(rank='182', name='Saints D/ST', position='DST', team='NO', posrank='DST11'), player(rank='183', name='Titans D/ST', position='DST', team='TEN', posrank='DST12'), player(rank='184', name='Matt Bryant', position='K', team='ATL', posrank='K4'), player(rank='185', name='Wil Lutz', position='K', team='NO', posrank='K5'), player(rank='186', name='Chris Boswell', position='K', team='PIT', posrank='K6'), player(rank='187', name='Robbie Gould', position='K', team='SF', posrank='K7'), player(rank='188', name='Jake Elliott', position='K', team='PHI', posrank='K8'), player(rank='189', name='Matt Prater', position='K', team='DET', posrank='K9'), player(rank='190', name='Harrison Butker', position='K', team='KC', posrank='K10'), player(rank='191', name='Adam Vinatieri', position='K', team='IND', posrank='K11'), player(rank='192', name='Graham Gano', position='K', team='CAR', posrank='K12'), player(rank='193', name='Bilal Powell', position='RB', team='NYJ', posrank='RB58'), player(rank='194', name='Peyton Barber', position='RB', team='TB', posrank='RB59'), player(rank='195', name='Chris Ivory', position='RB', team='BUF', posrank='RB60'), player(rank='196', name='Benjamin Watson', position='TE', team='NO', posrank='TE18'), player(rank='197', name='Vance McDonald', position='TE', team='PIT', posrank='TE19'), player(rank='198', name='Jared Cook', position='TE', team='OAK', posrank='TE20'), player(rank='199', name='Darren Sproles', position='RB', team='PHI', posrank='RB61'), player(rank='200', name='Austin Ekeler', position='RB', team='LAC', posrank='RB62'), player(rank='201', name='Corey Clement', position='RB', team='PHI', posrank='RB63'), player(rank='202', name='Spencer Ware', position='RB', team='KC', posrank='RB64'), player(rank='203', name='Chase Edmonds', position='RB', team='ARI', posrank='RB65'), player(rank='204', name='Frank Gore', position='RB', team='MIA', posrank='RB66'), player(rank='205', name='John Kelly', position='RB', team='LAR', posrank='RB67'), player(rank='206', name='Jonathan Stewart', position='RB', team='NYG', posrank='RB68'), player(rank='207', name='Javorius Allen', position='RB', team='BAL', posrank='RB69'), player(rank='208', name='T.J. Yeldon', position='RB', team='JAC', posrank='RB70'), player(rank='209', name='Mark Walton', position='RB', team='CIN', posrank='RB71'), player(rank='210', name='Eric Ebron', position='TE', team='IND', posrank='TE21'), player(rank='211', name='O.J. Howard', position='TE', team='TB', posrank='TE22'), player(rank='212', name='Tyrod Taylor', position='QB', team='CLE', posrank='QB21'), player(rank='213', name='Terrance Williams', position='WR', team='DAL', posrank='WR75'), player(rank='214', name='Danny Amendola', position='WR', team='MIA', posrank='WR76'), player(rank='215', name='Brandon Marshall', position='WR', team='SEA', posrank='WR77'), player(rank='216', name='John Brown', position='WR', team='BAL', posrank='WR78'), player(rank='217', name='Willie Snead', position='WR', team='BAL', posrank='WR79'), player(rank='218', name='Dede Westbrook', position='WR', team='JAC', posrank='WR80'), player(rank='219', name='Andy Dalton', position='QB', team='CIN', posrank='QB22'), player(rank='220', name='Ryan Tannehill', position='QB', team='MIA', posrank='QB23'), player(rank='221', name='Redskins D/ST', position='DST', team='WAS', posrank='DST13'), player(rank='222', name='Cardinals D/ST', position='DST', team='ARI', posrank='DST14'), player(rank='223', name='Dan Bailey', position='K', team='DAL', posrank='K13'), player(rank='224', name='Ryan Succop', position='K', team='TEN', posrank='K14'), player(rank='225', name='Tyrell Williams', position='WR', team='LAC', posrank='WR81'), player(rank='226', name='Ryan Grant', position='WR', team='IND', posrank='WR82'), player(rank='227', name='Quincy Enunwa', position='WR', team='NYJ', posrank='WR83'), player(rank='228', name='Jermaine Kearse', position='WR', team='NYJ', posrank='WR84'), player(rank='229', name='Taywan Taylor', position='WR', team='TEN', posrank='WR85'), player(rank='230', name='Courtland Sutton', position='WR', team='DEN', posrank='WR86'), player(rank='231', name='D.J. Chark', position='WR', team='JAC', posrank='WR87'), player(rank='232', name='Curtis Samuel', position='WR', team='CAR', posrank='WR88'), player(rank='233', name='Brandon LaFell', position='WR', team='CIN', posrank='WR89'), player(rank='234', name='Kendall Wright', position='WR', team='MIN', posrank='WR90'), player(rank='235', name='Charles Sims', position='RB', team='TB', posrank='RB72'), player(rank='236', name='Corey Grant', position='RB', team='JAC', posrank='RB73'), player(rank='237', name='Tavon Austin', position='RB', team='DAL', posrank='RB74'), player(rank='238', name="De'Angelo Henderson", position='RB', team='DEN', posrank='RB75'), player(rank='239', name='Wayne Gallman', position='RB', team='NYG', posrank='RB76'), player(rank='240', name='Terrance West', position='RB', team='NO', posrank='RB77'), player(rank='241', name='Jaylen Samuels', position='RB', team='PIT', posrank='RB78'), player(rank='242', name='Kalen Ballage', position='RB', team='MIA', posrank='RB79'), player(rank='243', name='Eli Manning', position='QB', team='NYG', posrank='QB24'), player(rank='244', name='Jameis Winston', position='QB', team='TB', posrank='QB25'), player(rank='245', name='Derek Carr', position='QB', team='OAK', posrank='QB26'), player(rank='246', name='Mike Gesicki', position='TE', team='MIA', posrank='TE23'), player(rank='247', name='Austin Hooper', position='TE', team='ATL', posrank='TE24'), player(rank='248', name='Ricky Seals-Jones', position='TE', team='ARI', posrank='TE25'), player(rank='249', name='Ryan Griffin', position='TE', team='HOU', posrank='TE26'), player(rank='250', name='C.J. Prosise', position='RB', team='SEA', posrank='RB80'), player(rank='251', name='Keke Coutee', position='WR', team='HOU', posrank='WR91'), player(rank='252', name='Taylor Gabriel', position='WR', team='CHI', posrank='WR92'), player(rank='253', name='Cowboys D/ST', position='DST', team='DAL', posrank='DST15'), player(rank='254', name='Seahawks D/ST', position='DST', team='SEA', posrank='DST16'), player(rank='255', name='Daniel Carlson', position='K', team='MIN', posrank='K15'), player(rank='256', name='Josh Lambo', position='K', team='JAC', posrank='K16'), player(rank='257', name='Hayden Hurst', position='TE', team='BAL', posrank='TE27'), player(rank='258', name='Gerald Everett', position='TE', team='LAR', posrank='TE28'), player(rank='259', name='Jake Butt', position='TE', team='DEN', posrank='TE29'), player(rank='260', name='Deon Cain', position='WR', team='IND', posrank='WR93'), player(rank='261', name='Trent Taylor', position='WR', team='SF', posrank='WR94'), player(rank='262', name='Travis Benjamin', position='WR', team='LAC', posrank='WR95'), player(rank='263', name='Geronimo Allison', position='WR', team='GB', posrank='WR96'), player(rank='264', name='Joe Williams', position='RB', team='SF', posrank='RB81'), player(rank='265', name='Alfred Blue', position='RB', team='HOU', posrank='RB82'), player(rank='266', name='Case Keenum', position='QB', team='DEN', posrank='QB27'), player(rank='267', name='Blake Bortles', position='QB', team='JAC', posrank='QB28'), player(rank='268', name='Joe Flacco', position='QB', team='BAL', posrank='QB29'), player(rank='269', name='Sam Bradford', position='QB', team='ARI', posrank='QB30'), player(rank='270', name='Josh McCown', position='QB', team='NYJ', posrank='QB31'), player(rank='271', name='Adam Humphries', position='WR', team='TB', posrank='WR97'), player(rank='272', name='Cole Beasley', position='WR', team='DAL', posrank='WR98'), player(rank='273', name='J.J. Nelson', position='WR', team='ARI', posrank='WR99'), player(rank='274', name='DaeSean Hamilton', position='WR', team='DEN', posrank='WR100'), player(rank='275', name='Dante Pettis', position='WR', team='SF', posrank='WR101'), player(rank='276', name='Boston Scott', position='RB', team='NO', posrank='RB83'), player(rank='277', name='Damien Williams', position='RB', team='KC', posrank='RB84'), player(rank='278', name='T.J. Logan', position='RB', team='ARI', posrank='RB85'), player(rank='279', name='Mike Gillislee', position='RB', team='NE', posrank='RB86'), player(rank='280', name='Justin Jackson', position='RB', team='LAC', posrank='RB87'), player(rank='281', name='Jeremy Hill', position='RB', team='NE', posrank='RB88'), player(rank='282', name='J.D. McKissic', position='RB', team='SEA', posrank='RB89'), player(rank='283', name='Robert Turbin', position='RB', team='IND', posrank='RB90'), player(rank='284', name='Amara Darboh', position='WR', team='SEA', posrank='WR102'), player(rank='285', name='Lions D/ST', position='DST', team='DET', posrank='DST17'), player(rank='286', name='Falcons D/ST', position='DST', team='ATL', posrank='DST18'), player(rank='287', name="Ka'imi Fairbairn", position='K', team='HOU', posrank='K17'), player(rank='288', name='Mason Crosby', position='K', team='GB', posrank='K18'), player(rank='289', name='Antonio Gates', position='TE', team='FA', posrank='TE30'), player(rank='290', name='Rico Gathers', position='TE', team='DAL', posrank='TE31'), player(rank='291', name='Blake Jarwin', position='TE', team='DAL', posrank='TE32'), player(rank='292', name='Luke Willson', position='TE', team='DET', posrank='TE33'), player(rank='293', name='Nick Vannett', position='TE', team='SEA', posrank='TE34'), player(rank='294', name='Corey Coleman', position='WR', team='CLE', posrank='WR103'), player(rank='295', name='Keelan Cole', position='WR', team='JAC', posrank='WR104'), player(rank='296', name='AJ McCarron', position='QB', team='BUF', posrank='QB32'), player(rank='297', name='Bears D/ST', position='DST', team='CHI', posrank='DST19'), player(rank='298', name='Steelers D/ST', position='DST', team='PIT', posrank='DST20'), player(rank='299', name='Browns D/ST', position='DST', team='CLE', posrank='DST21'), player(rank='300', name='Bengals D/ST', position='DST', team='CIN', posrank='DST22')]
```

Output (without `namedtuple`)

```
[['1', "Le'Veon Bell", 'RB', 'PIT', 'RB1'], ['2', 'Todd Gurley II', 'RB', 'LAR', 'RB2'], ['3', 'David Johnson', 'RB', 'ARI', 'RB3'], ['4', 'Antonio Brown', 'WR', 'PIT', 'WR1'], ['5', 'Ezekiel Elliott', 'RB', 'DAL', 'RB4'], ['6', 'Saquon Barkley', 'RB', 'NYG', 'RB5'], ['7', 'Alvin Kamara', 'RB', 'NO', 'RB6'], ['8', 'Julio Jones', 'WR', 'ATL', 'WR2'], ['9', 'DeAndre Hopkins', 'WR', 'HOU', 'WR3'], ['10', 'Odell Beckham Jr.', 'WR', 'NYG', 'WR4'], ['11', 'Kareem Hunt', 'RB', 'KC', 'RB7'], ['12', 'Keenan Allen', 'WR', 'LAC', 'WR5'], ['13', 'Dalvin Cook', 'RB', 'MIN', 'RB8'], ['14', 'Leonard Fournette', 'RB', 'JAC', 'RB9'], ['15', 'Melvin Gordon', 'RB', 'LAC', 'RB10'], ['16', 'Michael Thomas', 'WR', 'NO', 'WR6'], ['17', 'A.J. Green', 'WR', 'CIN', 'WR7'], ['18', 'LeSean McCoy', 'RB', 'BUF', 'RB11'], ['19', 'Christian McCaffrey', 'RB', 'CAR', 'RB12'], ['20', 'Devonta Freeman', 'RB', 'ATL', 'RB13'], ['21', 'Davante Adams', 'WR', 'GB', 'WR8'], ['22', 'Rob Gronkowski', 'TE', 'NE', 'TE1'], ['23', 'Mike Evans', 'WR', 'TB', 'WR9'], ['24', 'Adam Thielen', 'WR', 'MIN', 'WR10'], ['25', 'Larry Fitzgerald', 'WR', 'ARI', 'WR11'], ['26', 'T.Y. Hilton', 'WR', 'IND', 'WR12'], ['27', 'Doug Baldwin', 'WR', 'SEA', 'WR13'], ['28', 'Stefon Diggs', 'WR', 'MIN', 'WR14'], ['29', 'Travis Kelce', 'TE', 'KC', 'TE2'], ['30', 'Zach Ertz', 'TE', 'PHI', 'TE3'], ['31', 'Tyreek Hill', 'WR', 'KC', 'WR15'], ['32', 'Demaryius Thomas', 'WR', 'DEN', 'WR16'], ['33', 'Allen Robinson', 'WR', 'CHI', 'WR17'], ['34', 'Golden Tate', 'WR', 'DET', 'WR18'], ['35', 'Josh Gordon', 'WR', 'CLE', 'WR19'], ['36', 'Jerick McKinnon', 'RB', 'SF', 'RB14'], ['37', 'Joe Mixon', 'RB', 'CIN', 'RB15'], ['38', 'Jordan Howard', 'RB', 'CHI', 'RB16'], ['39', 'Alshon Jeffery', 'WR', 'PHI', 'WR20'], ['40', 'Amari Cooper', 'WR', 'OAK', 'WR21'], ['41', 'JuJu Smith-Schuster', 'WR', 'PIT', 'WR22'], ['42', 'Jarvis Landry', 'WR', 'CLE', 'WR23'], ['43', 'Kenyan Drake', 'RB', 'MIA', 'RB17'], ['44', 'Derrius Guice', 'RB', 'WAS', 'RB18'], ['45', 'Royce Freeman', 'RB', 'DEN', 'RB19'], ['46', 'Rashaad Penny', 'RB', 'SEA', 'RB20'], ['47', 'Sony Michel', 'RB', 'NE', 'RB21'], ['48', 'Ronald Jones II', 'RB', 'TB', 'RB22'], ['49', 'Alex Collins', 'RB', 'BAL', 'RB23'], ['50', 'Marshawn Lynch', 'RB', 'OAK', 'RB24'], ['51', 'Marvin Jones Jr.', 'WR', 'DET', 'WR24'], ['52', 'Robert Woods', 'WR', 'LAR', 'WR25'], ['53', 'Emmanuel Sanders', 'WR', 'DEN', 'WR26'], ['54', 'Michael Crabtree', 'WR', 'BAL', 'WR27'], ['55', 'Jay Ajayi', 'RB', 'PHI', 'RB25'], ['56', 'Derrick Henry', 'RB', 'TEN', 'RB26'], ['57', 'Dion Lewis', 'RB', 'TEN', 'RB27'], ['58', 'Mark Ingram', 'RB', 'NO', 'RB28'], ['59', 'Duke Johnson Jr.', 'RB', 'CLE', 'RB29'], ['60', 'Pierre Garcon', 'WR', 'SF', 'WR28'], ['61', 'Chris Hogan', 'WR', 'NE', 'WR29'], ['62', 'Brandin Cooks', 'WR', 'LAR', 'WR30'], ['63', 'Corey Davis', 'WR', 'TEN', 'WR31'], ['64', 'Aaron Rodgers', 'QB', 'GB', 'QB1'], ['65', 'Tom Brady', 'QB', 'NE', 'QB2'], ['66', 'Sammy Watkins', 'WR', 'KC', 'WR32'], ['67', 'Randall Cobb', 'WR', 'GB', 'WR33'], ['68', 'Devin Funchess', 'WR', 'CAR', 'WR34'], ['69', 'Will Fuller V', 'WR', 'HOU', 'WR35'], ['70', 'Cooper Kupp', 'WR', 'LAR', 'WR36'], ['71', 'DeVante Parker', 'WR', 'MIA', 'WR37'], ['72', 'Robby Anderson', 'WR', 'NYJ', 'WR38'], ['73', 'Greg Olsen', 'TE', 'CAR', 'TE4'], ['74', 'Delanie Walker', 'TE', 'TEN', 'TE5'], ['75', 'Evan Engram', 'TE', 'NYG', 'TE6'], ['76', 'Lamar Miller', 'RB', 'HOU', 'RB30'], ['77', 'Julian Edelman', 'WR', 'NE', 'WR39'], ['78', 'Kelvin Benjamin', 'WR', 'BUF', 'WR40'], ['79', 'Kerryon Johnson', 'RB', 'DET', 'RB31'], ['80', 'Cam Newton', 'QB', 'CAR', 'QB3']
```

Comment: What does this single underscore and asterisk `_,*data` mean here?

Comment: @Topto `_` is, by convention, a "throw away" variable. For instance, in the data above, a `[]` is created in the list comprehension that would contain the header values, however, are not garnered due to different table tags. Therefore, in order to find the rest of the data, unpacking is used.